.Net Multi Targeting the solution Issues
Compatibility Issues with .net framework Nuget code

We have an WEB API application which is written in VB.Net and running on .net framework 4.6.1.
The goal is to rewrite this into .Net 8 with c# and host it in Azure
The existing framework application is talking to the DB and other services using custom libraries which they call it Business logic layer these are nuget packages
This business logic layer is also written in VB and targeting .Net framework
There are issues with compatibility with these nuget libraries, now we are running into issues when trying to call few methods

Possible solutions I tried:
Since this is a legacy application(I am talking about the business logic layer) i cannot do much with this, i cannot rewrite the  whole logic which it does in my .net 8, so i tried

Porting from .net framework to .net standard
Multi Targeting the business logic layer to both .net framework and .net standard
work around solution suggested(RPC or LPC)(not yet tried this)

we opted out of porting since its very tedious work and the legacy application is still in active development where we cannot pull the new changes every time.
One thing i am interested in right now is the multi targeting the solution. The projects in business logic layer are still using old project style and not the new .net SDK version. I tried using the upgrade assistant in Visual studio and upgraded it Upgrade Assistant
Upgrade was successful and i got the new SDK style version of my VB project, and it build successfully with few reference issues which i fixed it. The problem is when i multi target it to .net standard 2.0, Iam running to lot of issues, the major issue is Visual studio throwing an exception which says about regressed version but it does not give what exactly it is.
when i reload it and try to build it, it builds but with thousands of errors, some are resolved once i click on the error and some might be fixed, but first issue is VS always says it is a faulted project
project File
=====================
6/27/2024 8:12:59 AM
LimitedFunctionality
System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'Workspace update handler 26008508' closed because of an exception: Attempted to push a project evaluation that regressed in version..
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: Attempted to push a project evaluation that regressed in version.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Handlers.AbstractEvaluationCommandLineHandler.EnqueueProjectEvaluation(IComparable version, IProjectChangeDiff evaluationDifference)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Handlers.CompileItemHandler.Handle(IWorkspaceProjectContext context, ProjectConfiguration projectConfiguration, IComparable version, IProjectChangeDescription projectChange, ContextState state, IManagedProjectDiagnosticOutputService logger)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<OnEvaluationUpdateAsync>g__ProcessProjectEvaluationHandlers|5(<>c__DisplayClass40_1& )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<OnEvaluationUpdateAsync>g__ApplyProjectEvaluation|2(IProjectVersionedValue`1 update, ContextState contextState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass43_1`1.<<OnProjectChangedAsync>g__ApplyInBatchAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass43_1`1.<<OnProjectChangedAsync>g__ApplyInBatchAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ReentrantSemaphore.StackSemaphore.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ReentrantSemaphore.StackSemaphore.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.OnceInitializedOnceDisposedUnderLockAsync.<ExecuteUnderLockCoreAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<OnEvaluationUpdateAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<OnWorkspaceUpdateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<OnWorkspaceUpdateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<OnWorkspaceUpdateAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__Action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
<--- (Inner Exception #0) 
===================


Firstly Is this the right approach for my problem, If yes how can i fix this or what other options do i have.
Even though if i can resolve this any idea if this works out to point to .net standard 2.0 nuget library from my .net 8 application with few tweaks?

multi-targeting is not a silver bullet that makes a project that is not compatible with .Net 8 to be compatible with .Net 8.

can you suggest any alternative

You've already opted out of what I would consider the best alternative ... because you find it "tedious" and apparently your developers refuse to stop using framework dependent code in their active development of class libraries.

the best alternative is not in my hands, to rewrite or port the code its a business decision and its tied to timelines budgets and what not

The exception you hit was fixed in https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/9606
